# Changes in behavior of Firefox when using the History-Back function

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, back, browser-history

I have an issue on Firefox. We have some pages on our site that have a 2-3 seconds load time.
If a link to these pages clicked there will be a class added to the body of the page that changes the layout.

I noticed that if you us the history-back button in Firefox the page is loaded while the Class is added still added to the body-tag. In Chrome the layout is like the page is freshly loaded.

I sure the Firefox used to have the same behaviour the Chrome. But resend this seam to have chanted. I have here a miniature script to illustrate the problem:

```html
<html>

  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('a.withWaitscreen').on({
            click:  function() { $("body").addClass("waiting");waitscreenCountdownInit();  }
        });
        $('button.withWaitscreen').on({
            click:  function() { $("body").addClass("waiting"); waitscreenCountdownInit();  }
        });
        $('form.withWaitscreen').on({
            submit:  function() { $("body").addClass("waiting"); waitscreenCountdownInit();  }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <style>
      .waiting{
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>

  <body  >

  </body>

  <a class="withWaitscreen" href="https://www.google.com/">
  test
  </a>

</html>
```

If you click the test link in Firefox and click the “back”-button in the browser the page will be red.
If you do the same in Chrome, the page will be white.

What causes this difference in behaviour? And how can this be change?

Comment: I noticed that the example code doesn’t has the same behaviour when you use the “Run code snippet”. You have to copy it to an HTML-file to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the following to the JS-Part of the file;

```js
$( window ).unload(function() {
  return "";
});
```

I’m not sure why this works, but it has the desired effect. (At least in Firefox 62.0)